# How to read Dropbox Public folder Images in HTML

Tags: jquery, html, dropbox

I want to read all images from a dropbox public folder in a loop using jquery loop and display them.

I have tried displaying single images [Simple Image](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/9d7ri25ku7xlj9u/WALL-E%20%281%29.jpg?dl=0) like this

"https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/9d7ri25ku7xlj9u/WALL-E%20%281%29.jpg?dl=0"

but if I have unknown number of images in dropbox public folder how can I access them all from dropbox??

Any starting point??

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dropbox Public folders don't currently offer any way to list all of the files contained in them, so there isn't a real way to do this. (Also, your sample link isn't a Public folder link anyway, but rather a "shared link". Public folder links used '/u/' instead of '/s/'.)

Anyway, one workaround here is to maintain your own index of all of the desired links as a single, pre-determined link. That is, you can host and update a text file at a specific link which would contain all of the other links. When necessary, you would download that index file to get the current list of links.